# SQLAlchemy: Add where clause based on count of many-to-many relation

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to create a model in which I can have different projects and each project has one or more authors. Since every author may be involved with multiple projects, this is a many-to-many relation. The setup for this is as follows

```
from typing import List
from typing import Optional

from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapped_column
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKeyConstraint
from sqlalchemy import Table
from sqlalchemy import Column
from sqlalchemy import UniqueConstraint

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass

author_project_association = Table(
    "author_project_associations",
    Base.metadata,
    Column(
        "author_id",
        ForeignKey("authors.id", onupdate="CASCADE", ondelete="CASCADE"),
        primary_key=True,
    ),
    Column(
        "project_id",
        primary_key=True,
    ),
    Column(
        "project_name",
        primary_key=True,
    ),
    ForeignKeyConstraint(
        ["project_id", "project_name"], ["projects.id", "projects.name"]
    ),
)


class Author(Base):
    __tablename__ = "authors"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(unique=True)

    projects: Mapped[List["Project"]] = relationship(
        back_populates="authors", secondary=author_project_association
    )


class Project(Base):
    __tablename__ = "projects"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)

    authors: Mapped[List[Author]] = relationship(
        back_populates="projects", secondary=author_project_association
    )
    calculations: Mapped[List["Calculation"]] = relationship(back_populates="project")
```

Now, I would like to query for a project, given its name and the list of authors. I came as far as

```
name = "Sample"
authors = ["John", "Kate"]

project = session.scalars(
    select(Project)
    .where(*[Project.authors.any(Author.name == current) for current in authors])
    .where(Project.name == name)
).first()
```

which I think should almost work, except that it currently only checks that all provided author names are indeed authors of the returned project, but that project may still have additional authors that are not part of the input list of authors.

How can I restrict the returned project to the one that matches the list of author names exactly?

My attempt was to try to embed something like a `where(len(Project.authors) == len(authors))` into my query, but that doesn't work and I also failed to get a sub-query that does the counting to work inside the `where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

After digging around in various resources, I finally got it to work by leveraging SQLAlchemy's hybrid attributes. Or, more specifically, with the help of hybrid attributes that make use of [correlated subqueries](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#correlated-subquery-relationship-hybrid).

Thus, I extended my `Project` class with the following members

```
class Project(Base):
    # as before
    
    @hybrid_property
    def author_count(self) -> int:
        return len(self.authors)

    @author_count.inplace.expression
    @classmethod
    def _author_count_expression(cls) -> SQLColumnExpression[int]:
        return (
            select(func.count()).select_from(author_project_association)
            .where(author_project_association.c.project_id == cls.id)
            .label("author_count")
        )
```

and then I could simply write the necessary `where` clause as

```
where(Project.author_count == len(authors))
```